# Strict version of foldl running infinitely

Tags: haskell, tail-recursion, ghci

I can't understand why the following function causes an infinite loop:

```
import Data.List

isTrue = foldl' (&&) False (repeat False)
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Both `foldl` and `foldl'` are defined in such a way that they have to go through the entire list before they can produce even a partial result (in fact there is no way to define them such that that wouldn't be the case). So neither works on infinite lists.

Answer (score 5):

These are the definitions of plain `foldl` and `repeat`:

```
foldl :: (b -> a -> b) -> b -> [a] -> b
foldl f z [] = z
foldl f z (x:xs) = foldl f (f z x) xs

repeat :: a -> [a]
repeat a = a : repeat a
```

Now, what happens when we try your definition of `isTrue`?  (Adapted to lazy `foldl`, of course, but this has the same problem as yours.)

```
foldl (&&) False (repeat False)
    == foldl (&&) False (False : repeat False)
    == foldl (&&) (False && False) (repeat False)
```

Now here's the key moment.  How does evaluation continue from here?  Well, it's a `foldl` thunk, so we have to figure out which of the two foldl equations to use—the one with the `[]` pattern, or the one with `x:xs`.  This means we must force the `repeat False` to see whether it's an empty list or a pair:

```
    == foldl (&&) (False && False) (False : repeat False)
    == foldl (&&) ((False && False) && False) (repeat False)
```

...and it'll continue doing this.  Basically, `foldl` can only terminate if it encounters a `[]`, and `repeat` never produces a `[]`.

```
    == foldl (&&) ((False && False) && False) (False : repeat False)
    == foldl (&&) (((False && False) && False) && False) (repeat False)
    ...
```

Using the strict `foldl'` means that the `False && False` terms get reduced to just `False`, and thus the code will run in constant space.  But it will still go on until it sees a `[]`, which will never come:

```
foldl' f z [] = z
foldl' f z (x:xs) = 
    let z' = f z x 
    in z' `seq` foldl' f z' xs

foldl' (&&) False (repeat False)
    == foldl' (&&) False (False : repeat False)
    == let z' = False && False in z' `seq` foldl' (&&) z' (repeat False)

       -- We reduce the seq by forcing z' and substituting its result into the 
       -- its second argument.  Which takes us right back to where we started...
    == foldl' (&&) False (repeat False)
    ...
```

These functions don't have any smarts that allow them to see that the accumulator will never be anything other than `False`.  `foldl'` doesn't know anything about how either `(&&)` nor `repeat False` work.  All it knows about are lists, and it will only finish on an empty one.

---

One of the tricky things about Haskell, for people who come from strict languages, is that they've learned that in such languages left folds are "better" than right folds because left folds are tail recursive and thus run in constant space, whereas right folds are true recursive and will blow the stack on long lists.

In Haskell, because of laziness, it's usually the other way around, so `foldl` and `foldl'` are the sucky ones, while `foldr`' is the "good" one.  For example, the following will terminate:

```
foldr (&&) False (repeat False)
```

Why?  Here's the definition of `foldr`:

```
foldr :: (a -> b -> b) -> b -> [a] -> b
foldr f z = []
foldr f z (x:xs) = f x (foldr f z xs)
```

Compare the second equation here with the one for `foldl`; `foldl'` is tail recursive, whereas `foldr` tail-calls `f` and passes the recursive `foldr` call as an argument.  This means that `f` gets to choose whether and when recurse down the `foldr`; if `f` is lazy on its second argument then the recursion is deferred until its result is required.  And if `f` discards it second argument, then we never recurse.

So, applied to my example:

```
foldr (&&) False (repeat False)
    == foldr (&&) False (False : repeat False)
    == False && foldr (&&) False (repeat False)
    == False
```

And we're done!  But note that this only works because `(&&)` is strict in its first argument, and discards its second argument if the first one is `False`.  The following variation goes into an infinite loop:

```
foldr (flip (&&)) False (repeat False)
```